# Heroku dyno not writing to file

Tags: python, heroku

I have a bot running on Heroku. This bot has some 'actions' that it is supposed to execute (those are dummies, just testing if everything is alright) and then write to file whatever action it did.

The funny thing is that on my local machine, after 6-8 hours of testing I had 3 entries (3 actions performed), but on Heroku the bot has been running for a day now, and no entries are present (thought this was Heroku's issue, but with both `cat` and `stat` it shows that the file is empty).

This is how I save the data to file:

```
 f = open('actions.txt', 'a')
 f.write(action)
```

Those are the file (`actions.txt`) permissions: `600`

I just want to store the actions the bot performed over a week or so to make sure everything is working well.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this file? Are you aware of [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)?

Comment: Oh. I was not aware of that. I just wanted to store the actions the bot performed over a week or so to make sure everything is working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to store the actions the bot performed over a week or so to make sure everything is working well

In that case you'll need a different approach to data persistence. Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) loses whatever changes you make to it every time your dyno restarts, which happens [at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).

A simple solution might be to store your data in PostgreSQL, which [Heroku supports out of the box](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). If you prefer other databases there are [many to choose from](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).